# PHP and SQL 2008 - Truncate table not working

Tags: php, sql, sql-server-2008

Why won't this table get Truncated?  No error is returned.  If I run the truncate SQL in SQL Server Management Studio, it truncates normally.

```
$truncate = "USE energyDB truncate table temp_energydata";

// Initiate connection to energyDB MS SQL server
    $connection = sqlsrv_connect($serverName, $connectionInfo);

    if( $connection ) {
     echo "Connection established.";
}else{
     echo "Connection could not be established.<br />";
     die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
}

    // Start the query on the Database server
    $statement = sqlsrv_query($connection,$truncate);

    if( $statement ) {
     echo "Truncate Query completed.";
}else{
     echo "Query not completed.<br />";
     die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
```

Comment: The output is not an error.  So it echos "Truncate Query completed".  But its not being truncated.

Comment: I'm not familiar with PHP, but is it possible that whatever connection libraries you're using do not `COMMIT` SQL commands by default?

Comment: Also make sure that the user specified in your $connectionInfo has permission to delete from the table.

Answer (score 0):

@user1745767

$truncate = "USE energyDB truncate table [temp_energydata]";

try like this it tooks hours for met too.

Comment: it should be on comment area of Question not as an answer. @Berk Calikoglu